# converting emoji to Arabic text in python

Tags: python, emoji, arabic

I have an Arabic string which has emoji and I want to convert them to text, I've found a function converts them to text but in English. How can I convert emoji to Arabic text?
here is my string and code:

my string: غوتشي فلورا الأسود فخم

after converting emoji: غوتشي فلورا الأسود فخم   two_hearts  two_hearts  two_hearts  two_hearts

```
import emoji
st="غوتشي فلورا الأسود فخم  "
st=emoji.demojize(st, delimiters=(" ", " "))
print(st)
```

thank you for your help.

Comment: if you can convert them into AR from EN you then either need to build up a corpus of translations then apply a mapping function to translate them into arabic. be warned, RTL, Emojis & English LTR is a nightmare in terms of formatting. Another method would be to use a translation API such as google translate.

Comment: I wrote: from googletrans import Translator and  st=translator.translate(st,src="EN",dest="AR") but it shows error:'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Answer (score 0):

in Python source code is u"\U0001F495"
so maybe you can try something with that?

edit: read op's post again.

so i found a site that translates emojis to any language
if قلبان is  maybe check it out / emojitranslate . com

i wonder if an api is the best way or maybe somehow importing a table of emoji conversions

Comment: op said he can translate it to English

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue and tackled it by creating a CSV file containing a comprehensive list of emojis and their equivalent Arabic text. You can access the file in the following [repository](https://github.com/a-ibrahimi/Arabic-Emojipedia).

To solve the problem, I wrote the following functions that convert the CSV file into a dictionary and then replace the emojis in a sentence with their corresponding text:

```py
import csv
import emoji

def build_emoji_dictionary(csv_file):
    emoji_dict = {}
    with open(csv_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        for row in reader:
            emoji = row[0]
            text = row[1]
            emoji_dict[emoji] = text
    return emoji_dict

def replace_emojis(emoji_dict, sentence):
    emojis = emoji.emoji_list(sentence)
    for emo in emojis:
        if emo['emoji'] in emoji_dict:
            # Replace the emoji with the corresponding text surrounded by asterisks
            sentence = sentence.replace(emo['emoji'], '*' + emoji_dict[emo['emoji']] + '* ')
    return sentence
```

Note that I surrounded the emoji text with asterisks in the code. You can omit them if you prefer. Also, make sure to install the emoji package if you haven't done so already.

To use this code, you can follow these steps:

```py
st="غوتشي فلورا الأسود فخم  "
emoji_dict = build_emoji_dictionary('./emojis.csv') #Assuming the CSV file is in the same directory
st=replace_emojis(emoji_dict, st)
print(st)
```

When you run the code, it should produce the following output:
[image]

Hope that helps!